# How to collect objects from map in blueprints

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

I have a plate with trigger(TriggerVolume) on it. When it overlapped cubes from map deleting. I've manually created references on cubes in blueprint to delete them but it seems very hard-coded. Is there any way to collect all references with "for loop"? And for more clarity - I'm using FPS template for this project.

Comment: GetAllObjectsOfClass

Comment: Thanks, but I've already considered this variant. The problem is that all map's objects are "static mesh actor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found solution: I've just found out that there are two different types of tags. One for components and one for actors. Here is my solution below.[image]